# Finish recursive promise function execution in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have 3 functions, func1() returns some api data to func2() and func2() is called from func3().Func2() has a Promise return type, in Func2() I resolve only of certain conditions are met else I want to call same Func2() until condition met but when I execute func3().I do not see my response from func2().I get error message "callback" argument must be a
function: TypeError: "callback" argument must be a function.

```
//func1()
const apiRequest = (options, func_callback) => {
  request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    let result = {
      body: body,
      error: err,
      res: res
    }
    func_callback(result);
  });
};
//func2
const getPromise = (options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    apiRequest(options, (response) => {
      if (response.error) {
        reject(response.error);
      }
      if (response.body.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
        console.error(`Error: Invalid token`);
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const payload = {
            url: 'https://abc',
            form:{},
            method: 'post'
          };
          request(payload, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
            }
            else {
              resolve(body);
            }
          });
        }).then((result) => {

          options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '+result;
          getPromise(options); // seems Issue having this line to call again
        });
      }
      else {
        resolve(response.body);
      }
    });
  });
};

// func3()
function getSession() {
  const options={url:''someurl',     
  getPromise.then(result => {
    console.log('all ID'+result); // I can not see result here
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('Error ', error);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `if` condition where you create the `new Promise(…).then(…)`, you never resolve the outer promise.

You could solve that by adding `resolve` in the right places, but you shouldn't create promises within promises anyway. You should promisify at the lowest possible level. Make `api_request` return a promise instead of having it take a callback.

```
// func1()
function apiRequest(options, func_callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else resolve({ body, res });
    });
  });
}
```

You can even reuse it, and use proper promise chaining:

```
//func2
functon getPromise(options) {
  return apiRequest(options).then(response => {
    if (response.body.hasOwnProperty('message')) {
      console.error(`Error: Invalid token`);
      const payload = {
        url: 'https://abc',
        form:{},
        method: 'post'
      };
      return apiRequest(payload).then(result => {
        options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '+result.body;
        return getPromise(options); // seems Issue having this line to call again
      });
    } else {
      return response.body;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only place where a promise should be created is in a function that wraps `apiRequest`.  That ("promisify-ing") wrapper, should do nothing other than build a promise that's resolved inside the callback.

```
//func1()
const apiRequest = (options, func_callback) => {
    request(options, (err, res, body) => {
        let result = {
            body: body,
            error: err,
            res: res
        }
        func_callback(result);
    });
};

// wrap the apiReqeust function in a promise.  place no other logic in here...
const apiRequestP = (options) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        apiRequest = (options, response => {
            (response.error)? reject(response.error) : resolve(response);
        })
    });
};
```

Now that there's a promise-returning wrapper *no other functions should call the callback style function*.

It looks like the intent of `func2` is to return a promise that makes a request and adds logic to check for and fix an auth challenge.  Do that by first creating a promise-returning function to fix auth for a request that's known to need it:

```
// return a promise to make a token request followed by an auth'd version
// of the request described in the options param
const remediateAuth = (options) => {
    console.error(`Error: Invalid token`);
    const authOptions = { url: 'https://abc', form:{}, method: 'post' };
    return apiRequestP(authOptions).then(response => {
        options.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '+response;
        return apiRequestP(options);
    }).then(response => response.body);
}
```

With that, func2 becomes very simple. Note how there are no other promises explicitly created.  Also note that this function is the layer that insures auth'd requests, so most of the rest of the app can call it, and not the foregoing, lower-level functions:

```
// was called func2
const authedRequest = (options) => {
    return apiRequestP(options).then(response => {
        return (response.body.hasOwnProperty('message'))? remediateAuth(options) : response.body;
    });
}
```

Comment: ,Thank you it helped me

Answer (score 0):

it's seems that in your function 'getPromise' you get (resolve, reject), but then inside the function you create another promise and then you create another 2 variables called (resolve, reject), that override the original resolve and then you really don't have any return value from getPromise

First assignment:

```
const getPromise = (options) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

and the second assignment:

```
console.error(`Error: Invalid token`);
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```